# Python EEL and PyInstaller Issue

Tags: python, pyinstaller, eel

I've recently created a program using eel, in this program I use the module *moviepy* to split the audio and the video of a file.

But when I try to put the whole project into an .exe file with PyInstaller, the app won't work.
The command I used is: `python -m eel main.py web`

I tried compiling the program **without** moviepy (I simply removed the import from main.py) and it perfectly worked.

So the problem is clearly moviepy which is not imported from PyInstaller.
Now I'm asking if there's any way to add moviepy dependencies using PyInstaller?

PS: Starting the source file works perfectly, it doesn't start only after compiled with PyInstaller

EDIT:

When I start the compiled .exe file with cmd, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Lucad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\moviepy\editor.py", line 84, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'moviepy.audio.fx.all' has no attribute 'audio_fadein'
[8740] Failed to execute script main
```

EDIT 2: FOUND A SOLUTION!

I read a thread where people say that moviepy has an error importing some modules, so all I had to do was modifying a file.

This is the link of the guide I followed: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/591

Thanks to everybody answering me!

Comment: What errors is it giving you?

Comment: it opens a cmd windows and instantly closes

Answer (score 0):

Did you try add moviepy explicitly to the path?

```
pyinstaller -y -D --name Whatever --clean --distpath="." -p "c:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\moviepy" yourpyfile.pyw
```

Comment: Not working, maybe moviepy has dependencies which are not automatically imported from PyInstaller, any way to import those modules too?

Comment: @Fearr Have you looked into hidden imports and hooks?: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html